# PHP url preg_match

Tags: php

I have a problem with this preg_match

```
function isValidURL($url){
    return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $url);
}
if(!isValidURL($url)){
    echo 'false';
} else 
    echo 'true';
```

For these links should display - true

```
/test.html
/testowa-strona_9067.html
/567890.html?get=test
/costam.html?get=2&f[]=k&f[]=k2
```

And for those false

```
/.html
/ąęśćzmn-ż.html
/testmhtml
/%67%68%89(i&.html?get=34
```

But it always displays true

Comment: Your regexp requires URLs to begin with `http://` or `https://`, I don't see how it could return true for any of those. I assume the URLs are actually like `http://hostname/test.html`

Comment: The regexp ends with `(/.*)?` so it allows any characters after the `/` that begins the pathname part of the URL.

Comment: if(preg_match( '/^\/[a-z0-9_]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z_0-9]+)*\.[_a-z]{2,5}'.'((:[0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$/i' ,$url)) my accualy code but still false on /567890.html?get=test  AND 
/costam.html?get=2&f[]=k&f[]=k2

Comment: You still end with `/.*`. `.*` matches anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
    die('Not a valid URL');
}
```